# How to boot Chromium OS verbosely?

Tags: troubleshooting, chromium-os

I'm attempting to boot the latest Chromium OS 32-bit build from [this site](http://download-chromiumos.appspot.com/).

Whilst I'm currently experiencing a typical installation issue (stuck at a black screen after initial loading screen), not being able to get a verbose output of the boot process is challenging.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts which can be fired before/while the loading screen appears?

Comment: This might be out of date but its worth a look https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-dev/PKfYGJ1ozE0

Comment: Thanks @JoelTaylor, I'd found similar infos, but these are for when you are building from the source yourself and I've just downloaded from the link above. If no secret keystrokes are revealed, I may have to go this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to try any of these but I did find this link which discusses a method for increasing the log level during Chromium's boot up:

- [True verbose boot?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-dev/PKfYGJ1ozE0)

This thread might also be relevant, titled: [Chromium OS‎ > ‎How Tos and Troubleshooting‎ > ‎ Kernel FAQ](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/kernel-faq). There are several examples on this page where they're adding more verbose switching to the kernel during boot, via `grub.conf`:

#### Example

```
menuentry "bzImage serial normal" {
linux /efi/boot/bzImage earlyprintk=serial,ttyS0,115200 console=ttyS0,115200 i 
nit=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait root=/dev/sda3 ro noresume noswap i915.modese 
t=1 loglevel=7
}
```

Comment: that was previously added about an hour ago in the comment above by Joel and unfortunately, does not address a downloaded build as the options need to be edited in the source before building.

Comment: @LeonStafford - sorry I skimmed the comment, didn't notice that one, what about the grub method?

Comment: No worries, I may mark it as accepted if no during-boot solutions turn up. The grub.conf is also on the burnt image file, but I'll see if I can dig into it and edit that option then re-burn without having to rebuild.

Comment: @LeonStafford have you tried the classic Linux ones? Hitting Esc or Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2-6 depending)?

Comment: @terdon, yep, I've done the typical geek finger mashing to no avail ;)

Comment: @LeonStafford - I'm not finding any additional leads.

Comment: @slm, I concur, awarding you the points and will dig more into if I can edit this .bin image with less effort than building the whole thing from source (which to be honest does sound like a much better way to get intimate with the OS).

Comment: @LeonStafford - yeah I would go all in and build it myself. Seems easier to debug and deal with it once you get over that hurdle.